# How to Create Iterative Forumla to calculate Z Score in R?

Tags: r, formula, calculation

I have a number of large data frames that have the following basic format, where the final two rows are a mean (d) and standard deviation (e) - although these are calculated elsewhere.

```
  a  b  c
a 4  3  4
b 3  2  6
c 2  1  8
d 3  2  6
e 1  1  2
```

I would like to create an iterative function that converts each raw data point into a z-score via the mean and sd value in d and e per column. The formula I would like to apply is ((x-mean)/SD).

The result would be the following:

```
   a   b  c
a  1   1  1
b  0   0  0
c -1  -1 -1
```

I don't mind if this is added to the end, created as a new dataframe or the data is converted.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean the `d` _row_ or column (missing)?

Comment: I would like to use the values in the d and e rows to convert the values in columns a - c using the formula ((x-d/e). The d ane e are missing from the second data frame because they do not need to be converted

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach, note that I do not use the mean/sd provided in the data but re-calculate it on the fly.
Also note that usually the data should be in a [`tidy` data representation](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/tidy-data.html), which in your case would mean that a, b, c would be in columns and then mean/sd would be either calculated on the fly or be in a separate column (note that this would reshaping the data, not shown here).

```r
# your input data
raw_data <- data.frame(
  a = c(4, 3, 2, 3, 1),
  b = c(3, 2, 1, 2, 1),
  c = c(4, 6, 8, 6, 2),
  row.names = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
)
raw_data
#>   a b c
#> a 4 3 4
#> b 3 2 6
#> c 2 1 8
#> d 3 2 6
#> e 1 1 2

# remove the mean/sd values
data <- raw_data[!rownames(raw_data) %in% c("d", "e"), ]
data
#>   a b c
#> a 4 3 4
#> b 3 2 6
#> c 2 1 8

# quick way to recalculate the values
means <- apply(data, 2, mean)
means
#> a b c 
#> 3 2 6
sds   <- apply(data, 2, sd)
sds
#> a b c 
#> 1 1 2

z_scores <- apply(data, 2, function(x) (x - mean(x)) / sd(x))
z_scores
#>    a  b  c
#> a  1  1 -1
#> b  0  0  0
#> c -1 -1  1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

## Edit / Full Code

The following code is a bit longer but most of it is spent on getting the data into the right (long/tidy) format.
If you have any questions, feel free to use the comments.

Note that the [`tidyverse`](https://www.tidyverse.org/) is really helpful, but might need some time to get used to. The code used here is mostly [`dplyr`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/) (included in the tidyverse).
If you understand the functions: `%>%` ([pipe](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/pipes.html)), `group_by()`, `mutate()`, `summarise()`, and `pivot_longer/wider()` you got everything.

```r
library(tidyverse)
# use your original dataset again
raw_data <- data.frame(
  a = c(4, 3, 2, 3, 1),
  b = c(3, 2, 1, 2, 1),
  c = c(4, 6, 8, 6, 2),
  row.names = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
)

### 1) Turn the data into a nicer format

# match-table how to rename the variables
var_match <- c(d = "mean", e = "sd")
# convert the raw data into a nicer format, first we do some minor changes 
# (variable names, etc)
data_mixed <- raw_data %>% 
  # have the rownames as explicit variable
  rownames_to_column("metric") %>%
  # nicer printing etc
  as_tibble() %>% 
  # replace variable names with mean/sd
  mutate(metric = ifelse(metric %in% c("d", "e"),
                      var_match[metric], metric))

data_mixed
#> # A tibble: 5 x 4
#>   metric     a     b     c
#>   <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 a          4     3     4
#> 2 b          3     2     6
#> 3 c          2     1     8
#> 4 mean       3     2     6
#> 5 sd         1     1     2

# separate the dataset into two: 
# data holds the values
# data_vars holds the metrics mean and sd
data      <- data_mixed %>% filter(!metric %in% var_match) %>% select(-metric)
data_vars <- data_mixed %>% filter(metric %in% var_match)

data
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>       a     b     c
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     4     3     4
#> 2     3     2     6
#> 3     2     1     8

data_vars
#> # A tibble: 2 x 4
#>   metric     a     b     c
#>   <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 mean       3     2     6
#> 2 sd         1     1     2


# turn the value dataset into its longer form, makes it easier to work with it later
data_long <- data %>% 
  pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = "var", values_to = "val")

data_long
#> # A tibble: 9 x 2
#>   var     val
#>   <chr> <dbl>
#> 1 a         4
#> 2 b         3
#> 3 c         4
#> 4 a         3
#> 5 b         2
#> 6 c         6
#> 7 a         2
#> 8 b         1
#> 9 c         8

# turn the metric dataset into another long form, allowing easy combination in the next step
data_vars2 <- data_vars %>% 
  pivot_longer(-metric, names_to = "var", values_to = "val") %>% 
  pivot_wider(var, names_from = metric, values_from = val)

data_vars2
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>   var    mean    sd
#>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 a         3     1
#> 2 b         2     1
#> 3 c         6     2

# combine the datasets
data_all <- left_join(data_long, data_vars2, by = "var")

data_all
#> # A tibble: 9 x 4
#>   var     val  mean    sd
#>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 a         4     3     1
#> 2 b         3     2     1
#> 3 c         4     6     2
#> 4 a         3     3     1
#> 5 b         2     2     1
#> 6 c         6     6     2
#> 7 a         2     3     1
#> 8 b         1     2     1
#> 9 c         8     6     2

## 2) calculate the z-score

# now comes the actual number crunchin!
# per variable var (a, b, c) compute the variable val_z as the z-score
data_res <- data_all %>% 
  group_by(var) %>% 
  mutate(val_z = (val - mean) / sd)

data_res
#> # A tibble: 9 x 5
#> # Groups:   var [3]
#>   var     val  mean    sd val_z
#>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 a         4     3     1     1
#> 2 b         3     2     1     1
#> 3 c         4     6     2    -1
#> 4 a         3     3     1     0
#> 5 b         2     2     1     0
#> 6 c         6     6     2     0
#> 7 a         2     3     1    -1
#> 8 b         1     2     1    -1
#> 9 c         8     6     2     1


## 3) make the results more readable

# lastly pivot the results to its original form
data_res_wide <- data_res %>% 
  select(var, val_z) %>% 
  group_by(var) %>% 
  mutate(id = 1:n()) %>% # needed for easier identification of values
  pivot_wider(id, names_from = var, values_from = val_z)

data_res_wide
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>      id     a     b     c
#>   <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     1     1    -1
#> 2     2     0     0     0
#> 3     3    -1    -1     1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Note that the c column is different than in your expected output, not really sure how you got there.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I messed up my formula in excel when I made the example. I have updated column c. I will try your solution, thank you

Comment: So this has got me pretty close. However, I would like to not recalculate the means and SD because these actually come from a control data set. I also have these separate in vectors but could make them columns as you suggest if that helps?

Comment: See my update above. If that helped you, please consider upvoting the answer!